# Debian Lenny: is my system up-to-date?

Tags: debian, debian-lenny

Howto find out if a Debian Lenny 64-bit is up-to-date?

When I run `sudo aptitude update` it only tells me something like

```
...
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny Release
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org lenny/updates Release
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org squeeze Release
...
Reading package lists...
```

But no updates seems to be actually performed.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aptitude update
aptitude upgrade
```

Comment: Correct version today is `aptitude safe-upgrade` although upgrade still works, but aptitude gives a warning.

Comment: so what is `aptitude update` used for when it doesn't update the system?

Comment: @Vokuhila-Oliba: It fetches (updates) the lists that contain information about every application in the repositories. **Based** on this lists `aptitude upgrade` performs the update.